# Ubuntu does not wake up after suspension/hibernation

Tags: ubuntu, grub, suspend

I am using ubuntu 18.04 lts. After I close the lid (for 1 min+), ubuntu refuses to wake up. It flashes an error screen instead: [image]

Does it have to do with grub?

I usually work around the issue by rebooting...but it takes a long time since I am using a hdd.

Comment: Check to see if there are any hints in the logs. You should be able to change `tty` with `Ctrl-Alt-Fn` where `n` is 1-6 (you are probably already on 7). Then log in and check the logs.

Comment: That doesn't look like an error screen to me. Have you tried Alt + F7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error screen; it is a console window. It probably means that your Ubuntu switches to another vty when suspending.

Try switching to another vty by using the Ctrl-Alt-Fx key combos, or by using Ctrl-Alt-<left> or Ctrl-Alt-<right>. That will probably get you your GUI back.